# Getting invalid domain and request from iOS client application are blocked while integrating google RECAPTCHA Enterprise

Tags: ios, swift, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to integrate google recaptcha enterprise, I have successfully generated the site key api key from the console,
I am getting following two issue

1. While loading the "I'm not a robot" checkbox UI in web view , I am getting "invalid domain name" error

   [image]

   I bundled the mock html then loading it in a webView, here is my html file code

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js" async defer></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key"></div>
        </body> </html>
   ```
2. While creating assessment, which is 2nd step of integration process, I am getting the following response

   > Please check the assessment request

   ```
   let urlString = String(format: "https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/%@/assessments?key=%@",
                              projectID,
                              apiKey)         

           var parameters = [String: Any]()
           parameters = ["event":["token": token,
                                  "siteKey": siteKey,
                                  "expectedAction": "other"
                                 ]]
           let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
           ]

           let request = Alamofire.request(urlString,
                                           method: method,
                                           parameters: parameters,
                                           encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                           headers: headers)

           NSLog("Sending request to \(request.request?.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
           request.validate()
           request.responseJSON { response in

               switch response.result {
               case .success:
                   print("success case ")
                   if response.result.error != nil {
                       completion(false, response.result.error! as! String)
                   }
                   completion(true, result)
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("failure case ")
                   completion(false, (response.result.error?.localizedDescription)!)
                   break
               }
           }
   ```

   and getting the following response for the assessment api

   ```
   {
       "error": {
           "code": 403,
           "message": "Requests from this iOS client application <empty> are blocked.",
           "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
           "details": [
               {
                   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                   "reason": "API_KEY_IOS_APP_BLOCKED",
                   "domain": "googleapis.com",
                   "metadata": {
                       "consumer": "projects/some_id",
                       "service": "recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com"
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

how can i resolve both issues?

Comment: Did you add "Domain Name Validation Verify the origin" when setting up the recaptcha ?